# Writing an empty iso image with c++ on unix

Tags: c++, unix, ecma, iso9660

For the sake of simplicity I will not include my code as most of it contains hard-coded binary/hex/ascii strings to replicate sectors in accordance to the [ECMA](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-199.pdf) guidelines set for the ISO 9660 standards (see the image below). The main objective of this task is to write a blank iso image that follows the standards referenced above. My question is as follows:

With data gathered for all of the following sectors: 
[image: sectors] 
How can I feed the binary data into some serializer to create an empty iso image on my unix system? I haven't been able to find any useful examples of how one would go about doing this. Maybe I'm not looking in the right place (who knows...)? Any and all help is more than appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an iso9660 image file e.g. for a CD burning software or to mount it, there is no special file format to do so. Simply write the data sector by sector in binary mode in a file.

[Wikipedia: ISO image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image)

Comment: Thank you sir. This at least gives me somewhat of a heading now. I feel like the documentation should be made a little more clear.